# WINDOWS 10 JAVA_HOME is not working

Tags: windows-10, java-home

My system is Windows 10 64 bit

I have created an environment variable "JAVA_HOME" and updated the path but, still system is showing "The JAVA_HOME" environment variable is not defined This environment variable is needed to run this program"

Also, echo %JAVA_HOME% is not displaying the path

Please review the attached screenshots.

[image: Command prompt]

[image: System Variable]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to close and reopen cmd.exe or restart the computer to get JAVA_HOME to propagate to your command prompt.

If cmd was open when you set the variables they will not be available in that session.

Comment: I found this true too with JAVA_HOME (need to reboot).
But not when I set a path in the Path:  for entries in the system variable Path I didn't need to reboot. (Win7/8/10)  Why is that?

Comment: I added JAVA_HOME in the environment variables list of Windows 10 pointing to D:\Apps\jdk-17.02, where I have extracted this jdk files, and in the system variable path I added this '%JAVA_HOME%\bin; and in my cmd console I see that path statement has '%JAVA_HOME%\bin' where as it supposed to translated to 'D:\Apps\jdk-17.02\bin' but not. why?