# Why does JAVA_HOME fail in Path when the exact path of JAVA_HOME works in the same place?

Tags: java, windows

I note to begin with that a very related question has been asked before, but the answer was to restart the system which does not work for me.  Here is that link if anyone is interested:

[WINDOWS 10 JAVA_HOME is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33771315/windows-10-java-home-is-not-working)

Also, there are several similar discussions about Path, and the answers seem to involve the order in which entries appear in the path, or a registry reset, however that does not appear to be the case here, since my working and non-working solution use the same order and the same registry settings.  I did not list these since there are several.

But my case is that I have set JAVA_HOME:

[image]

And then I have used JAVA_HOME in Path (at the bottom, not the top):

[image]

And then javac -version fails at the command line:

[image]

But if I replace JAVA_HOME with its exact contents in Path:

[image]

Then javac -version works:

[image]

So, seemingly a pointless question since I can make it work.  However, I am wondering why partly in the interest of knowing what is going on and partly in the interest of knowing if JAVA_HOME will fail if used elsewhere.

Comment: You need to add `JAVA_HOME\bin` to path. `javac` is not in the top level dir

Comment: @flakes but isn't %JAVA_HOME%\bin the last line of my path (second image)?

Comment: Also, I did try JAVA_HOME (followed by \bin) without the enclosing %% as in my example and this failed too, but again, the simple path contents of JAVA_HOME (followed by bin of course) does work ...

Comment: @RCM define both variables in the same scope, not system vs. user.

Comment: In `cmd` type `SET` and see what the path is set to. maybe it's invalid at some point. Could also be that the user variable isnt getting considered in the system vars. iirc if you create a path in user vars it will get appended to the system

Comment: It does appear to be that the JAVA_HOME has to be a system variable not a user variable.  I guess maybe that's obvious?!  Not to me, lol!  Martin Zeitler since you were first to say this, do you want points for the answer?  Write it and I'll choose you.  Otherwise in a day or so I'll write it just so others can easily find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `%JAVA_HOME%` variable is in the user variables scope, you must be logged in from that specific user account <sup>(*Checked on Windows 7).</sup>

Or as Martin Zeitler has mentioned in the comments, best option is to put both variables in the same scope.

Comment: OK, I will accept this one since Martin Zeitler never came back and wrote his comment as an answer...even though he was the first to point out what I think is the main issue...JAVA_HOME must be a system variable (not a user variable) .